# How to convert a System.IO.Packaging.Package to HTML?

Tags: c#, .net, html, ms-word, openxml

Microsoft Word interoperability classes will let you get at [a property called `WordOpenXML`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608426/how-to-convert-the-wordopenxml-property-into-a-system-io-packaging-package).  This represents a package that will be stored - zipped up - in a `.docx` file and can be opened by Microsoft Word.  However, is there a way to convert this `Package` to other formats, notably HTML?

I read in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55113/how-do-i-convert-a-docx-to-html-using-asp-net/55121#55121) to an old question that "Word 2007 has an API that you can use to convert to HTML.  [...] You can find documentation around the API, but I remember that there is a convert to HTML function in the API."  I'm not 100% sure which API that guy is talking about but perhaps it's `System.IO.Packaging.Package` or something similar.  I can't seem to find any "convert to HTML function"; does anyone know how you can convert a `Package` format Word document into HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API in question is probably the Save method on the document; when a file type of HTML is chosen, Word transforms the document into HTML, and applies the appropriate styling.

Chances are, given that the `docx` format is XML, there is an XSLT transformation of some sort going on; this is just speculation, but it's not far-fetched, as XSLT is commonly used to create HTML from XML.

That said, what you are looking for probably does *not* reside in the [`Package` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.package.aspx), nor should it.  The `Package` class is used for creating packages of content, not with the transformation of that content.

However, there's nothing stopping you from providing the transformation of that content; you can get the XML that is the basis of the Word document and then apply your own XSLT which would produce the HTML that you want.