# Converting from 'WordOpenXML' to In-Memory System.IO.Packaging.Package

Tags: c#, stream, ms-word, openxml-sdk

When using VSTO 2012 to manipulate an MS Word Document, I see that the document has a `WordOpenXML` string property, which is an XML representation of all the files constituting the .docx package which would be saved to disk when saving this Word document as a .docx.

I want to convert this string to an equivalent `System.IO.Packaging.Package` object **in-memory**.

The [SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608426/how-to-convert-the-wordopenxml-property-into-a-system-io-packaging-package) is very similar. Indeed, the OP even mentions 'in memory' in his question. However, the answers given involve saving the Package to disk using the `System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage.Open()` method. I do not want to save the Package to disk and then have to open it again using the `WordprocessingDocument.Open()` method. Rather, I want everything to be done in memory and not involve the file system at all.

I see that `WordprocessingDocument.Open()` has an overload that takes a `Stream`. However, I'm not sure how I would prepare such a `Stream` from the `WordOpenXML` string, although I suspect the post referenced above gives much of the answer.

Comment: It's been a while, I know, but do you recall whether DevTun's answer was the solution to your problem at the time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this method to get an in memory stream from the WordOpenXml string:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Returns a System.IO.Packaging.Package stream for the given word open XML.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="wordOpenXML">The word open XML.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static MemoryStream GetPackageStreamFromWordOpenXML(string wordOpenXML)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(wordOpenXML);
        XNamespace pkg =
           "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage";
        XNamespace rel =
            "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships";
        Package InmemoryPackage = null;
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (InmemoryPackage = Package.Open(memStream, FileMode.Create))
        {
            // add all parts (but not relationships)
            foreach (var xmlPart in doc.Root
                .Elements()
                .Where(p =>
                    (string)p.Attribute(pkg + "contentType") !=
                    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"))
            {
                string name = (string)xmlPart.Attribute(pkg + "name");
                string contentType = (string)xmlPart.Attribute(pkg + "contentType");
                if (contentType.EndsWith("xml"))
                {
                    Uri u = new Uri(name, UriKind.Relative);
                    PackagePart part = InmemoryPackage.CreatePart(u, contentType,
                        CompressionOption.SuperFast);
                    using (Stream str = part.GetStream(FileMode.Create))
                    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(str))
                        xmlPart.Element(pkg + "xmlData")
                            .Elements()
                            .First()
                            .WriteTo(xmlWriter);
                }
                else
                {
                    Uri u = new Uri(name, UriKind.Relative);
                    PackagePart part = InmemoryPackage.CreatePart(u, contentType,
                        CompressionOption.SuperFast);
                    using (Stream str = part.GetStream(FileMode.Create))
                    using (BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(str))
                    {
                        string base64StringInChunks =
                       (string)xmlPart.Element(pkg + "binaryData");
                        char[] base64CharArray = base64StringInChunks
                            .Where(c => c != '\r' && c != '\n').ToArray();
                        byte[] byteArray =
                            System.Convert.FromBase64CharArray(base64CharArray,
                            0, base64CharArray.Length);
                        binaryWriter.Write(byteArray);
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (var xmlPart in doc.Root.Elements())
            {
                string name = (string)xmlPart.Attribute(pkg + "name");
                string contentType = (string)xmlPart.Attribute(pkg + "contentType");
                if (contentType ==
                    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml")
                {
                    // add the package level relationships
                    if (name == "/_rels/.rels")
                    {
                        foreach (XElement xmlRel in
                            xmlPart.Descendants(rel + "Relationship"))
                        {
                            string id = (string)xmlRel.Attribute("Id");
                            string type = (string)xmlRel.Attribute("Type");
                            string target = (string)xmlRel.Attribute("Target");
                            string targetMode =
                                (string)xmlRel.Attribute("TargetMode");
                            if (targetMode == "External")
                                InmemoryPackage.CreateRelationship(
                                    new Uri(target, UriKind.Absolute),
                                    TargetMode.External, type, id);
                            else
                                InmemoryPackage.CreateRelationship(
                                    new Uri(target, UriKind.Relative),
                                    TargetMode.Internal, type, id);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    // add part level relationships
                    {
                        string directory = name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf("/_rels"));
                        string relsFilename = name.Substring(name.LastIndexOf('/'));
                        string filename =
                            relsFilename.Substring(0, relsFilename.IndexOf(".rels"));
                        PackagePart fromPart = InmemoryPackage.GetPart(
                            new Uri(directory + filename, UriKind.Relative));
                        foreach (XElement xmlRel in
                            xmlPart.Descendants(rel + "Relationship"))
                        {
                            string id = (string)xmlRel.Attribute("Id");
                            string type = (string)xmlRel.Attribute("Type");
                            string target = (string)xmlRel.Attribute("Target");
                            string targetMode =
                                (string)xmlRel.Attribute("TargetMode");
                            if (targetMode == "External")
                                fromPart.CreateRelationship(
                                    new Uri(target, UriKind.Absolute),
                                    TargetMode.External, type, id);
                            else
                                fromPart.CreateRelationship(
                                    new Uri(target, UriKind.Relative),
                                    TargetMode.Internal, type, id);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            InmemoryPackage.Flush();
        }
        return memStream;
    }
```