# How to generate stream to save Word document at remote location?

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, word-addins

I am working on Word AddIn project. I am trying to generate a `MmoryStream` to save that stream to remote location. Basically What I am supposed to do is take the content of ActiveDocument by using `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.WordOpenXML` and save it at remote location.

Now for that I am converting this entire string which I am getting with `WordOpenXML` property to MemoryStream by [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22604518/3881188).

After that, I am passing this MemoryStream to HttpContent and for that I have written below code.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostDocumentAsync(SendAttachement sendAttachement)
        {
            if (sendAttachement == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sendAttachement));
            }

            using (var _client = new HttpClient(clientHandler, false))
            {
                _client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
                _client.BaseAddress = _URLParams.HostName;
                _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("UserNameOrEmail", Settings.Default.UserName);
                _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Password", Settings.Default.Password);
                _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Word-Addins");
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();

                foreach (var contentItem in sendAttachement.Contents)
                {
                    HttpContent content = contentItem.streamContent;
                    content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
                    {
                        FileName = contentItem.FileName
                    };
                    form.Add(content);
                }


                var uri = _URLParams.APIPath + "/" + _URLParams.AbsolutePath + "?ClientId=" + sendAttachement.ClientId + "&RoomId=" + sendAttachement.RoomId + "&FolderId=" + sendAttachement.FolderId + "&ConflictStatus=" + sendAttachement.ConflictStatus;

                return await _client.PostAsync(uri, form);

            }
        }
```

Above code gives me `200 OK` but as I download the uploaded file, It gives me error that `Microsoft Word cannot open this document because some part of this file is missing is invalid.`

Now I am unable to figure out that Whether am I creating wrong/corrupted stream or anything else.

Sorry for this silly question but I have tried as much as possible solutions I could have done it.

Comment: I would first remove the whole 'uploading stream' part of the problem to limit where the issue is. Instead of uploading, try saving the binary stream to disk and see if it will still open as a Word doc. If it won't, your problem is in the way you're serializing the doc to binary stream; if it will, then your problem is with transferring. Also, if the problem is in the sending of the stream, yo're going to have to show your code for your receiving method